# Prefetch to optimize web page speed (SPA)

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, prefetch

I have 2 pages, one is a user list, and one is user detail. There's a gallery on the user detail page, how can I use prefetch to make the app experience better? I can push the gallery images to the user list API. But it makes the first page (user list) slower?

I have another idea, prefetch only when the user hovers to a user in the user list page, and when they click on the link, they won't have to fetch the images from scratch. What do you think?

Comment: So the hover part doesn't sound like prefetching, it actually sounds like the opposite, but you could probably achieve it [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62871284/load-third-party-iframe-in-react-after-page-load-so-that-the-iframe-does-not-af) but with `onHover` or something instead of scroll

Comment: maybe I misunderstood prefetching? if my user list api return the images, how do I prefetch them without sacrifice the speed load on the user list page?

Comment: I think you're asking about the concept behind SSGs. They are superfast and pre-rendered. Gatsby, Nextjs as some wonderful ssgs to look into if coding in react.

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi but does nextjs render the image when the response is just a img URL? how?

Comment: I'm sure a youtube tutorial or crashcourse will give much clearer answer than I can here.

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi how would you optimize if you're in my shoe, forget about my suggestion about prefetching

Comment: Instead you could optimize your gallery view to show only 3-4 thumbnails rather than a the entire photos in full size. You can then use pagination or infinite-scroll to gradually load more data.