# PageSpeed Insights diagnostic "Ensure text remains visible during webfont load"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

I'm getting the diagnostic on [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/)

```
Ensure text remains visible during webfont load
Leverage the font-display CSS feature to ensure text is user-visible while webfonts are loading. Learn more.
URL
    
Potential Savings
…v1/aWB4m0aac….woff2(fonts.gstatic.com)     10 ms
…v21/nuFvD-vYS….woff2(fonts.gstatic.com)    10 ms
…v13/6xK3dSBYK….woff2(fonts.gstatic.com)    10 ms
```

And I'm trying to correct it by changing

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/display=swap" />
```

But this actually throws a console error

---

I know that [PageSpeed Insights recommends to add](https://web.dev/font-display/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown) `font-display: swap` to `@fontface`, but I don't know what `@fontface` is.

I'm using **Bootstrap** and **Gatsby**

I know there's also `gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader`. Is there a way to use this to avoid this diagnostic?

---

These are all the times font-family shows up in my program. I'm using `scss` so most of them are variables

I only specify a font once in my program, and I think bootstrap chooses the font the rest of the time

```
blockquote > p {
   font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

---

Update, I'm using this plugin now

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
  options: {
    fonts: [
      `Montserrat`,
      `Helvetica Neue`,
      `Helvetica`,
      `Arial`
      
    ],
    display: 'swap'
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@font-face` is a rule that allows you to use multiple `font-family` rule instead of loading it in each selector.

Among all font plugin of fonts in Gatsby I recommend [`gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-google-fonts/) because it allows you to display and swap between fonts.

```
 plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [
          `limelight`,
          `source sans pro\:300,400,400i,700` // you can also specify font weights and styles
        ],
        display: 'swap'
      }
    }
  ]
```

It's really useful since it's preloading the font without affecting the display (due to the `swap` property).

With Gatsby,   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />` this configuration is automated so you don't need to touch it. It's better to pre-render them using a plugin, since it's the power of Gatsby.

Comment: How do I know which fonts to write in there though? I have one font that I use for blockquotes(Montserrat) and then I think bootstrap chooses the rest of the fonts

Comment: Then you should load Montserrat and Bootstrap fonts there. Bootstrap effects in a really bad way the performance due to the weigh of the package. With custom fonts it will load properly, I don't know if it will work with Bootstrap fonts...

Comment: Do you know how I can find out what the bootstrap fonts are?

Comment: Inspecting your HTML output on your web or viewing your network. You should be able to see if there is an extra request for CSS fonts.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question thats not related to this post, I'm trying to add a plugin to load [recaptcha](https://github.com/pittica/gatsby-plugin-recaptcha) but I only need it on two of my web pages. Do you know how to specify to only include it on those pages? Otherwise i think PageSpeed considers it ununsed javascript.

Comment: I've recently implemented the same dependency. You only need to add `<Recaptcha>` component on your page. Let's say `/contact`, so add it to `contact.js`. If all your pages shares the same layout, you will need to check the location with something like: `if(location==='/your-page') return <Recapcha>`

Comment: I mean in terms of gatsby-config, if it's imported in there then won't all my pages have it?

Comment: And I just do `<div className="m-auto m-sm-0 g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="myKey"></div>`

Comment: It's not imported in `gatsby-config.js` it's imported directly in your pages/components as a component itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217780/discussion-between-ferran-buireu-and-sam).

Comment: So I get this now

Avoid chaining critical requests 1 chain found

Maximum critical path latency: 1,130 ms

Initial Navigation
http://example.com
https://example.com
/css?family=…(fonts.googleapis.com) - 40 ms, 0 KiB

Comment: I also get these browser errors

URL
Description
/css?family=…(fonts.googleapis.com)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
/css?family=…(fonts.googleapis.com)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
/css?family=…(fonts.googleapis.com)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
/css?family=…(fonts.googleapis.com)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
/css?family=…(fonts.googleapis.com)

I clicked the urls though and they lead to a font page

Answer (score 4):

You made a minor mistake.

It should be

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=TheFontYouWantToUse&display=swap />`

If you do a forward slash as shown in your example it will result in a 404 not found, hence the console error. Replace it with a URL parameter (`&`) and it should work fine.

`@fontface` is just a way of loading a font from within a stylesheet.

For example within your main CSS file you could add the following and that would also load the font in. Notice the `font-display` property set to `swap`.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Pacifico Regular'), local('Pacifico-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pacifico/v12/FwZY7-Qmy14u9lezJ-6H6MmBp0u-.woff2) format('woff2');
  font-display: swap;
}
```

Comment: Are the fonts I want to use just any font that's mentioned in my css? I'm using bootstrap so don't they specify some of the fonts?

Comment: I have added the other way of including a font within stylesheets to my answer. Probably the fonts are included that way if they aren't included via a `<link>` so have a look through your style sheets and see if you can find `@font-face`.

Comment: please note `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />` will not do anything by itself so just double check that, you have to specify the font with the `family=` parameter. That may actually be a problem with your theme.