# Nextjs struggling to improve LCP for text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, seo, next.js13

I am trying to improve my LCP score by optimizing my text but still now it's same and I don't know why my LCP not improving. see the screenshot:

[image]

It is saying that **'Popular Products for Daily Shopping'** is my Largest Contentful Paint element, and it's taking almost 3,590 ms. If I remove this text from my page.js, then another text appears, and if I remove that text, another text shows up again for LCP.

I tried to laod google font on my server side but didn't work.

my page.js

```
import HomePage from '../components/Home/Home'
import { headers } from 'next/headers'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({subsets:['latin']})

export default async function Home() {return (
    <>
    
    <main className={inter.className}>
      <HomePage />
    
     
    </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

here is my Popular Products section

```
<div className="mb-10 flex justify-center">
        <div className="text-center w-full lg:w-2/5">
          <h2 className="text-xl lg:text-2xl mb-2 text-emerald-500 font-semibold">
            Popular Products for Daily Shopping
          </h2>
        
        </div>
      </div>
```

My text is only one line, and I don't understand how a one-line text can be the Largest Contentful Paint (LCP) of my page when my images are well-optimized, and there isn't even any LCP for images.

I also tried load google font in my layout.js but didn't help to improve LCP:

layout.js

```
 <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"/>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>

      </head>
      <body >... others code
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your page.js file I see that you have not provided display:swap. When your LCP is textual content you need to ensure web fonts are handled properly. display swap let's you do that.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/fonts#google-fonts

```
// If loading a variable font, you don't need to specify the font weight 
const inter = Inter({   
    subsets: ['latin'],
    display: 'swap', <-- this is important
 })
```

Here are some other relevant links:

[Largest contententful paint (LCP) on lighthouse is a p tag. (Using gatsby)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333077/largest-contententful-paint-lcp-on-lighthouse-is-a-p-tag-using-gatsby)

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/performance/font-display/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown

Comment: display: 'swap', did same results