# Pagespeed insights avoid chaining critical request only lists Initial navigation followed by my domain twice

Tags: lighthouse, pagespeed-insights

I'm trying to optimize my page speed, and I am receiving this error. I'm kind of confused by what its trying to tell me because it's only listing my domain twice?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is merely informing you of the resources requested that are required to render the "above the fold" content.

As the initial query was to http and you redirected to https that still counts as 2 requests so it is just informing you.

You need to realise the stuff under "diagnostics" has nothing to do with scoring and is purely there to help you identify potential issues.

In reality there is nothing you need to do here (other than maybe change your redirect to a 301 instead of a 307 redirect as that would be a be a "permanent redirect" instead of a "temporary redirect").

Comment: How would I change the redirect to a 301? I don't really know a lot about that. I'm using Gatsby

Comment: normally this is done through .htaccess or similar. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that in Gatsby but I am pretty sure that is something that is easy to Google as most people will have done that. Phrases such as "gatsby redirect to https" and "301 redirect gatsby" should yield results.